# Separating classes in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing my first chrome extension and I can't seem to find any way to pull in functionality in a RequireJS type way..

I just want to be able to write a class in 1 JS file and pull its functionality in to my background.js file and use it, to keep things tidy.

I've googled about and can't find anything! What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: are js you refer to are either content scripts or extension html js??

Comment: Not content scripts, stuff in background page - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1

If you want to pull `class.js` functionality in to background.js, you can just append it to scripts array in manifest.json.

Like this,

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["class.js","background.js"]
  },
  ...
}
```

This means background.js will load after class.js is loaded. So that you can use all functioanality of `class.js` in `background.js`.

---

## 2

If you want to do this in `require.js` way, you should use background.html instead of `background.js`.

Like this,

### manifest.json

```
{
    "background": {
      "page": "background.html"
    },
    "description":  "Background example",
    "name":         "Background example",
    "version":      "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
     "web_accessible_resources": [
       "scripts/require-jquery.js",
       "scripts/main.js"
    ],
}
```

As you see you must add script files that you will use to [web_accesible_resource](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources) array.

### background.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery+RequireJS Sample Page</title>
        <!-- This is a special version of jQuery with RequireJS built-in -->
        <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require-jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```